# What to do with old vent stack pipe?

Tags: hvac

I’ve got an old vent pipe that was for the furnace or hot water, that comes up through floor in closet, and 90’s to exterior wall. Currently it just has a towel stuffed in it.

The furnace room already has louvered vents to the basement for airflow, but I was curious on folks opinion of what to do with this old pipe?

I’m re-doing the floors upstairs and am looking at removing it or repurposing if possible. Thoughts?

It lets in a lot of cold air, but wasn’t sure if furnace need exterior venting?[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like a combustion makeup air duct to me. Are you sure it's not? Combustion air shouldn't be drawn from the interior (as your mention of vents to the basement implies).

Comment: please show us a pic of the furnace and h/w to see how it is vented/intake. Many upgraded systems no longer need the furnace room itself to be vented, but it's important to be 100% sure.

Comment: The condition of the inside of the pipe (very clean) strongly suggests that it's an air intake vent, **not** an old disused exhaust vent. If so, it should not be plugged.

Comment: Thanks guys - updated with more pictures. The pipe is totally clean on the inside. Furnace room /HW is 8x10 ft. Gas furnace and HW (new 2017). Not high efficiency with pvc intake / outake.

Answer (score 1):

Those both appear to be atmospherically vented without independent intake pipes.

You should have at least one pipe equal to the size of the outflow pipes if not two feeding that room with exterior air.

If your house depressurizes CO will be pulled into that room instead of exhausting.

Unplug it immediately.  Also make sure you have a working CO detector in that room.

Answer (score 0):

What you show in your picture is very likely a critical "Fresh Air Intake Vent".

Furnaces and other gas appliances such as hot water tanks and dryers require the oxygen in air to burn the gas. If there is insufficient oxygen, the burning will be incomplete there will be carbon monoxide in the exhaust, and not all of the carbon monoxide will be be pulled out of the furnace through the exhaust vent (or "chimney"), leaving some of it to linger and enter the house. This exacerbates the lack of oxygen at the burner which in turn produces more carbon monoxide, and is a potentially a deadly situation.

To prevent this deadly cycle, the furnace room must be adequately supplied with air from outside the room. The best supply comes from outside the house. As gas burns and exhaust leaves the house, fresh air is pulled in.

In some jurisdictions, at some point in the past, it was sufficient to have combustion air pulled in from the house into the furnace room, through a grill in the wall or in the door (as in your photo). The lower pressure in the house would then cause fresh outside air to be pulled in through cracks and through the HVAC fresh air intake. This intake supplies the recirculating air with fresh air, and is not to be confused with the fresh air for combustion, although sometimes they are effectively the same intake.

[image]

Pulling in outside cold & dry air into the house does not help with heating efficiency, and so it is avoided or minimized where possible.

Now we have high efficiency furnaces with a dedicated and isolated combustion air intake: a pipe leads from outside straight into the furnace itself.

[image]

However, if the furnace room is also a laundry room with a dryer (electrical or gas), then the supply through a grill is not adequate, and an intake from outside must be provided.

So it is possible that the basement or furnace room once had a dryer and with its removal the intake was deemed a cold nuisance and plugged.

If your house is still cracky old, and the dryer is in a separate room with its own window or intake, you can likely keep that pipe plugged, but check with your city. In any case, get CO detectors for the basement, the sleeping quarters and the furnace room.

Ideally you would open that intake, and also get CO detectors. Opening it will most likely make the furnace room cooler but improve the overall efficiency, since the burning would not use up warm humid house air, and avoid pulling in cold dry air into other spaces of the house.